# как разрешить всплывающие окна?

Tags: javascript, html, браузер

как разрешить всплывающие окна во всех браузерах или при загрузке страницы обязательно спросить пользователя разрешение на использование всплывающих окон?

Comment: никак, это невозможно.

Answer (score 0):

Это вопрос безопасности, поэтому разрешение пользователя будет спрашиваться для каждого отдельного браузера.